# What am I doing wrong in the following Matlab recursion programming project?

Tags: matlab, recursion, programming

Write a recursive function (using Matlab) moreFactors(a,b,fact) that does the following:

1. Takes as an input 3 positive integers.
2. Of the two integers a and b, the function returns the integer that has the most factors fact.
3. If both integers a and b have the same amount of factors fact, the function will return the larger integer.

Test your function with the following:

> > result=moreFactors(24,32,3)

result = 24

(24 = 3^1 · 2^3 , 32 = 2^5 )

> > result=moreFactors(32,24,3)

result = 24

> > result=moreFactors(80,168,2)

result = 80

(80 = 2^4 · 5, 168 = 2^3 · 3 · 7)

> > result=moreFactors(100,50,5)

result = 100

(100 = 2^2 · 5^2 , 50 = 2 · 5^2 )

Note: function must be recursive!

[Wrapper Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVG0H.png)

[Inside Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGHwb.png)

Comment: Do you have a specific question or problem?

Comment: My function provides an error when I call it, but I'm having trouble understanding why. Are there any blatant errors in my code that I'm missing?

Comment: Especially with recursion, this entire problem can be done in a much smaller program if you think about it the right way. Hint: if a and b are both divisible by fact then you can divide both of them by fact without changing which one of the two has more factors. This gives you a nice equation for moreFactors that you can use to set up the recursion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about debugging a programming assignment.

Comment: Where would be a better place to post this?

Comment: The regular stack overflow site for programming would be a good place to post it